# VBA sending embedded OLE PDF with mailto:

Tags: vba, pdf, excel, ole

Problem:
embedded a PDF into a Excel workbook.
This PDF is a feedback form which has a send to mail recipient button.
Without embedding it to Excel sending works, when embedded sending causes Excel to crash.

My idea is to open the OLEObject, save the embedded PDF temporary, close the OLEObject
and open the saved PDF so that it runs in a Acrobat instance.
Opening the OLEObject already works by using:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetName).Shapes(OLE_Name).Select
Selection.Verb Verb:=xlOpen
```

But im struggling with the following steps.
How to do this?
Possible other ways?

WIN7, Office 2010, Acrobat Reader

Comment: Are you trying to simply send the PDF as an attachment?  Is there any reason you would need to open the PDF before sending it?

Comment: The embedded PDF is a feedback form. The reason why i want to open it is because the user should fill in some data before sending it. The sending function is integrated into the PDF and it sends the PDF as a mail attachment.

Comment: OK. OLEObjects are notoriously difficult to work with. I used to have some code that tried to do something similar with an XML/Text file, but it did not work on that type of file and does not seem to work on PDF either.  Acrobat supports *some* automation but not much. I will see if I can figure something out.

Comment: Just FYI, this [may not be possible to do](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/235dde1a-13bb-4f07-8eb4-04ef1121a747/export-a-pdf-file-from-powerpoint-with-vba?forum=officegeneral).  Why do you *need* to have this file embedded in Excel Workbook? That seems not very reliable way of storing/transfering files & data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. OLEObjects are notoriously difficult to work with. I have done some searching because it seems hard to believe this is not supported.  This was my first attempt to use a `Shell` command to copy the OLE and paste it to a known directory.

However, you can't copy/paste a PDF embedded object, which means you can't use a `Shell` command to copy/paste it to a temporary folder/file path. So that won't work.

The consensus seems to be that this is not really possible; all you can do with embedded PDF is open them.  See [here](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/819139-save-embedded-file.html) and, [here](http://forums.adobe.com/message/1161924#1161924) which referencing this PDF says:

> See the "AxAcroPDFLib.AxAcroPDF" section under OLE Automation. Those are the only methods you have available to you from Reader

And also, [here](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1139303):

> What you are doing relies on you knowing how to interact with the particular class which may be OK if you only have a couple of types and know what they are but in general, unless (a) the Class supports Automation and (b) you know the commands to issue this can't work.

The class does not really support the sort of automation you desire.

**Possible Solution**

Use Acrobat and WinAPI

If you have Acrobat installed, then I believe you may be able to do this possibly using WinAPI to get the hWnd of the Acrobat instance, and control it that way. [I have perused some documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/acrobat_sdk/9.1/Acrobat9_1_HTMLHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=Acrobat9_HTMLHelp&file=IAC_API_OLE_Objects.103.1.html), but I do not have Acrobat and so I am not able to test.